# How to pass in datetime parameters to your stored proc using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime-select

so i have a stored proc that i am passing in datetime params too return the data... The problem is i want to pass in default dates and times but not sure how to do this as i can only see datetime.now... here is my code...

```
public void RefreshLabeldata(int selectedProduct, DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd)
{
    BizManager biz = new BizManager();

    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    dt = biz.GetTotalPacked(
        shiftStart 
      , shiftEnd
      , selectedProduct).DataSet;
    labeltotal.Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TotalPacked"].ToString();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Refreshdata(214, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(-1));
        BindDropDownList();
        RefreshLabeldata(214, DateTime.Today , DateTime.Today);
        ...
    }
...
}
```

I want to pass in the date that my sql stored proc accepts i.e shiftStart 2016-06-06 06:00 shiftEnd 2016-06-06 14:00.

I know my datetimes are all wrong :) i am still trying to figure this part out.

Comment: good question, that is wrong, i am trying to learn how to change these.

Comment: still in my learning phase :)

Comment: Please look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning how to pass DateTime as a parameter then please go through DateTime documentation. [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/working-with-datetime-using-C-Sharp/)

`DateTime.Today` will contain value something like `6/6/2018 12:00:00 AM`. If you know exact date and time, then instead of using `DateTime.Today` you can use `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider)`.

where *dateString* will be your date in string format.

*format* will contain date time format e.g. `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

*provider* will be cultureInfo. For more details [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

To summarize, try with

```
RefreshLabeldata(214, DateTime.ParseExact("2018-06-06", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) , DateTime.ParseExact("2018-06-07", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: it says parseexact doesnt exist in the type DateTime

Comment: I updated my answer.. remove new keyword and just use `DateTime.ParseExact()` implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bAI1Nh

Comment: hi, i tryed this but it is giving me todays date when i debug for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To use current date with your requested format, try this:

```
 Refreshdata(214, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this help for you ...

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh mm}", YourDate)
```

Refer this link :http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/